# How do I 'POST' to a page and populate the Form Data?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I inspected one of my own pages thinking 'how does the username and password get passed to the server' and when I ran fiddler I have the following:

```
POST http://vls.pete/Login.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: vls.pete
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://vls.pete/Login.aspx
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=yc2zsqveono2vm000d4liexp
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------21724139663430
Content-Length: 2054

-----------------------------21724139663430
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATE"

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
-----------------------------21724139663430
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET"


-----------------------------21724139663430
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT"


-----------------------------21724139663430
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTVALIDATION"

/wEWBQKpta7uDALlkKHqBQK/x+yDBgL2koVLAvSJ7pkMkU0QjNaNcJgsKX6cXUSVq18/Kqfcx+yfjUfB2mLQt64=
-----------------------------21724139663430
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$mainContent$ucLoginPanel$tbUserName"

admin
-----------------------------21724139663430
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$mainContent$ucLoginPanel$tbPassword"

password
-----------------------------21724139663430
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$mainContent$ucLoginPanel$lbLogin"

Login
-----------------------------21724139663430--
```

What im wondering is how I would call a page programatically from javascript and implement single login for a user, what would happen to the cookies etc?.

Any advice on how to log in a user via script or any other method much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp), then the browser's cookies will be sent to the server with the request.  Further, any cookies the server returns in its response will be added to the browser session.  So if you log your user on with this mechanism then cookie-based authentication should work.

Note that you will only be able to read these response cookies from JavaScript using `document.cookies` after the next page load.

Comment: thanks mikey (fellow house music fan) thats great, can I populate form data of the XMLHttpRequest ?

Comment: Here's an example of sending form data as either a GET or a POST: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php